# How to jump from step definition to feature file step in JavaScript, using control/cmd + click does not work?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, cucumberjs, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using a Cypress with Cucumber testing framework and trying to jump from `step_definition` to `.feature` file step, but the <kbd>Cmd + Click</kbd> does not work (like in Java). The jumping works from `.feature` step to the `step_definition` but does not work the other way around.

My project structure is:

```text
root
|_cypress
|__e2e
|___features
|___step_definitions
```

Is there any way that this can be achieved?

I have tried using IntelliJ IDEA and WebStorm with their respective Cucumber plugins, but still no luck.

I have added a image to better understand what I am asking.
[screenshots of step_definition and .feature file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8XR9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this feature is not yet supported, please vote for [WEB-25522](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25522) to be notified on any progress with it